# How to add ::before pseudo-class to this element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Hello all you smart CSS people... I've got a Doozey!

[https://tritonmedicine.com/services](https://tritonmedicine.com/services/) is the page in question

[It's the title down the page a bit, next to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRFOR.jpg)

How do I style ONLY the ::before pseudo-class/id for the "preventative care" title? I'm trying to add the word "ADULT" in front of it, but if I use the id#1506, it won't work. If I only use the class (.tab-pane.active), it puts "ADULT" in front of every active title. What am I doing wrong here?

This DOESN'T work:

```
#1506.tab-pane.active > div:nth-child(2) > div > h3::before {
    content: 'ADULT';
}
```

This DOES work (but styles them all, which I don't want):

```
.tab-pane.active > div:nth-child(2) > div > h3::before {
    content: 'ADULT';
}
```

Any assistance is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select `id` that start with number in **CSS selectors**

For more [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

**Solution**

try somthing like these `tab1506` or `tabPane1506` or `tp1506`

But there is another solution of your problem, you can use

**Attribute selector:**

```
[id="1506"].tab-pane.active > div:nth-child(2) > div > h3::before {
    content: 'ADULT';  
}
```

For more [read here](https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/)

Comment: You are awesome man, thank you so much! I had no idea you couldn't begin with a number. I appreciate the help :)